# Как записать числа в массив

Tags: c#, массивы, запись

Вводятся числа например: 2;1;3;2.5;15 и т.д.
Их нужно записать в массив, не понимаю как это сделать, у меня выводятся просто нули.

Мой код:

```
Console.Write("числа массива: ");
string[] str = Console.ReadLine().Split(";");
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
   decimal[] num1 = new decimal[str[i].Length];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal[] num1 = new decimal[str.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
  num1[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Я думаю стоит ещё указать автору, что Split работает с Char, поэтому двойные кавычки не прокатят.

Comment: @SoulOFTrue правда? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0 `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", "2;1;3;2.5;15".Split(";")));` у меня работает и выводит `2 1 3 2.5 15`.

Comment: Возможно не хватает InvariantCulture, но это не точно